# how to inspect the content of persistent volume by kubernetes on azure cloud service

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, azure-cloud-services

I have packed the software to a container. I need to put the container to cluster by Azure Container Service. The software have outputs of an directory `/src/data/`, I want to access the content of the whole directory.

After searching, I have to solution.

1. use Blob Storage on azure, but then after searching, I can't find the executable method.
2. use Persistent Volume, but all the official documentation of azure and pages I found is about Persistent Volume itself, not about how to inspect it.

I need to access and manage my output directory on Azure cluster. In other words, I need a savior.

Comment: You need a saviour? But are you [holding out for a hero?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bWcASV2sey0) A PersistentVolume is, in part, an abstraction layer between the pod definition and a storage medium. You don't inspect the PV, you inspect the underlying storage medium. Unless you mean `kubectl describe persistentvolume NAME`.

Comment: [This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-dynamic-pv) shows how to use AzureFile as the backing storage for a PersistentVolume.

Comment: I have tried this documentation,  but I had not connect the container and the AzureFile. I will have another try now.

Comment: Make sure you create a share with that name on the Azure portal (go to the Storage Account, click "Files", click "+ File Share" in the toolbar).

Comment: The example [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/blob/master/staging/volumes/azure_file/azure.yaml) may help with accessing using the AzureFile volume type in the first place.

Comment: @张泽栋 Did above  tips helped ? Did you manage to solve problem ?

Answer (score 25):

As I've explained [here](https://frank.sauerburger.io/2021/12/01/inspect-k8s-pvc.html) and [here](https://k8s.sauerburger.com/t/pvc-inspect), in general, if you can interact with the cluster using `kubectl`, you can create a pod/container, mount the PVC inside, and use the container's tools to, e.g., `ls` the contents. If you need more advanced editing tools, replace the container image `busybox` with a custom one.

**Create the inspector pod**

```yaml
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: pvc-inspector
spec:
  containers:
  - image: busybox
    name: pvc-inspector
    command: ["tail"]
    args: ["-f", "/dev/null"]
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /pvc
      name: pvc-mount
  volumes:
  - name: pvc-mount
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: YOUR_CLAIM_NAME_HERE
EOF
```

Alternatively, I've created a templating service to simplify these kind of tasks:

```
kubectl apply -f 'https://k8s.sauerburger.com/t/pvc-inspect.yaml?image=busybox&name=pvc-inspector&pvc=YOUR_CLAIM_NAME_HERE'
```

**Inspect the contents**

```
kubectl exec -it pvc-inspector -- sh
$ ls /pvc
```

**Clean Up**

```
kubectl delete pod pvc-inspector
```

Comment: This works for me ! . The context was to inspect files in a PVC for a CronJob. Because once the CronJob executes the pod can no longer be accessed (and hence any files on the associated PVC) they was need to find a way to access these files.