# Accessing/saving Kubernetes persistent volume data locally

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes

is there a way I can access/view/store the data stored in Kubernetes persistent volume locally? I saw a post mentioning using a dummy pod to inspect data, but it didn't say how. It can be mounting or adding an additional pod or anything. I would appreciate any insight on this matter. Thanks ahead!

Comment: You mean like that one here: [Stackoverflow.com: How to inspect the content of pesistent volume ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49529005/how-to-inspect-the-content-of-persistent-volume-by-kubernetes-on-azure-cloud-ser)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to inspect the content of persistent volume by kubernetes on azure cloud service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49529005/how-to-inspect-the-content-of-persistent-volume-by-kubernetes-on-azure-cloud-ser)